# Removing duplicates from a csv file using ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, duplicates

I have a csv file with the following data

```
Sno Scenario    Result  Description
1   Sce_1   Pass    Pass
2   Sce_2   Pass    Pass
1   Sce_1   Fail    Failed
```

In this scenario I have 2 same serial numbers. I would like to see only the row which has result `Pass` and remove the rest of the duplicate rows.

I have tried the following but still am not able to get it!

```
CSV.open('New.csv', 'w') do |csv|
   CSV.read('Merged_files.csv').uniq!{|x| x[1]}.each do |row|
       csv << row
   end
end
```

Can anyone help me in getting the logic!

Comment: The csv file is as below:
Sno Scenario  Result  Description
1     Sce_1      Pass    Pass
2     Sce_2      Pass    Pass
1     Sce_1      Fail      Failed

Comment: You should use `uniq` rather than `uniq!`, as the latter returns `nil` if no change is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For purposes of illustration, I've added a fourth row to your table:

```
require 'csv'

arr = CSV.read("x.csv")
  #=> [["Sno", "Scenario", "Result", "Description"],
  #    ["1", "Sce_1", "Pass", "Pass"],
  #    ["2", "Sce_2", "Pass", "Pass"],
  #    ["1", "Sec_1", "Fail", "Pass"],
  #    ["3", "Sec_3", "Fail", "Pass"]]
```

You can remove the unwanted elements as follows:

```
arr[1..-1].group_by(&:first).map { |_,a|
  (a.size > 1) ? a.reject { |e| e[2]=="Fail" } : a }
  #=> [[["1", "Sce_1", "Pass", "Pass"]],
  #    [["2", "Sce_2", "Pass", "Pass"]],
  #    [["3", "Sec_3", "Fail", "Pass"]]]
```

The steps:

```
h = arr[1..-1].group_by(&:first)
  #=> {"1"=>[["1", "Sce_1", "Pass", "Pass"],
  #          ["1", "Sec_1", "Fail", "Pass"]],
  #    "2"=>[["2", "Sce_2", "Pass", "Pass"]],
  #    "3"=>[["3", "Sec_3", "Fail", "Pass"]]}

h.map { |_,a| (a.size > 1) ? a.reject { |e| e[2]=="Fail" } : a }
  #=> [[["1", "Sce_1", "Pass", "Pass"]],
  #    [["2", "Sce_2", "Pass", "Pass"]],
  #    [["3", "Sec_3", "Fail", "Pass"]]]
```

If, for a given `Sno/Scenario` there is at most one `"Pass"` row, you can use [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) instead:

```
a = h.flat_map { |_,a| (a.size > 1) ? a.reject { |e| e[2]=="Fail" } : a }
  #=> [["1", "Sce_1", "Pass", "Pass"],
  #    ["2", "Sce_2", "Pass", "Pass"],
  #    ["3", "Sec_3", "Fail", "Pass"]]
```

If you wish to add back the header row:

```
a.unshift(arr.first)
  #=> [["Sno", "Scenario", "Result", "Description"],
  #    ["1", "Sce_1", "Pass", "Pass"],
  #    ["2", "Sce_2", "Pass", "Pass"],
  #    ["3", "Sec_3", "Fail", "Pass"]]
```

If you want to exclude all "Fail" rows, even if there is no correponding "Pass" row (as for `Sno == "3"`), you can do this:

```
h.flat_map { |_,a| a.reject { |e| e[2]=="Fail" } }
  #=> [["1", "Sce_1", "Pass", "Pass"],
  #    ["2", "Sce_2", "Pass", "Pass"]]
```